# link to flash content not working

Tags: flash, hyperlink, shockwave

I linked a graphic flash content to my homepage with:

```
<object width="710" height="260" data="http://www.admaris.net/vindagarden/HiiMEX_Intro/fs_aux.html" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="data" value="http://www.admaris.net/vindagarden/HiiMEX_Intro/fs_aux.html" >
<param name="src" value="http://www.admaris.net/vindagarden/HiiMEX_Intro/fs_aux.html" >
</object>
```

However, when I go to the homepage of my site, the space where it is supposed to be is just blank. You can check it yourself here: http://www.hiimex.se/

The flash graphic which should be there can be viewed here: http://www.admaris.net/vindagarden/HiiMEX_Intro/fs_aux.html

Now the unusual part is that it works on my computer on Internet Explorer - my Modzilla however does not show it and on most other computers (also on Internet Explorers) it also does not show.

Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this:

```
<object width="710" height="260" data="http://www.admaris.net/vindagarden/HiiMEX_Intro/fs_aux.html" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="data" value="http://www.admaris.net/vindagarden/HiiMEX_Intro/fs_aux.html" >
<param name="src" value="http://www.admaris.net/vindagarden/HiiMEX_Intro/fs_aux.html" >
</object>
```

try embedding the .swf file with the following code:

```
<object width='710' height='260' id='player1' name='player1'>
   <param name='movie' value='http://www.admaris.net/vindagarden/HiiMEX_Intro/HiiMEX_Intro.swf'>
   <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'>
   <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>
   <param name='flashvars' value='file=playlist.xml&dock=true'>
</object>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Integrate flash file in myanimation.swf  to your falsh file.
 It may help you

Comment: You mean like this? <object width="100" height="100" data="http://www.admaris.net/vindagarden/HiiMEX_Intro/HiiMEX_Intro.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="data" value="http://www.admaris.net/vindagarden/HiiMEX_Intro/HiiMEX_Intro.swf" />
<param name="src" value="http://www.admaris.net/vindagarden/HiiMEX_Intro/HiiMEX_Intro.swf" />
</object>